# Dynamic Lambda Expression builder crashes on enumerates

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

In order to be able to dynamically use strings in LINQ, I use the following helper function I built in order to construct a Lambda expression from a string:

```
public static Func<ObjectToOrder, object> GetSortExpression<ObjectToOrder> (string field) {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ObjectToOrder), "objectToOrder");
            var mySortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<ObjectToOrder, object>>(Expression.Property(param, field), param);
            return mySortExpression.Compile();
        }
```

I'll explain how this function works in the following example: I have a class Person with three of attributes:

```
class Person {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public EnumerateType Type {get;set;}
}

enum EnumerateType {
   Normal = 1,
   Premium = 2
}
```

Then inside a List of Person, I would use my helper function to order by any attribute this way:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
//Create people in the list
//...
people = people.OrderBy(GetSortExpression<Person>("Name")).ToList();
people = people.OrderBy(GetSortExpression<Person>("Age")).ToList();
people = people.OrderBy(GetSortExpression<Person>("Type")).ToList();
```

With the attributes Name and Age it works fine, but with the Type attribute it raises the following exception when executing "var mySortExpression = Expression.Lambda>(Expression.Property(param, field), param);" of the helper function:

```
Cannot use a expression of type 'EnumerateType' for the returned value type 'System.Object'
```

Why is that so? What should I do in order to solve it and be able to create a lambda expression for enumerates (I thought internally enumerates are integers)?

Thank you

EDIT: I've noted that it also crashes with any DateTime attribute.

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/233505/23354 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it fails for `Age` too:

> Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'

The *immediate* issue is that you need a conversion (a box in this case) from a value-type to an `object`:

```
var mySortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<ObjectToOrder, object>>(
    Expression.Convert(
        Expression.Property(param, field),
        typeof(object)
    ), param);
```

However, using `object` here could in-and-of-itself be problematic. I suggest looking at [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet)

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell for your answer, with the conversion I could solve the Exception issue. I am trying your dynamic LINQ methods, yet my VS doesn't recognize the function ApplyOrder. Where could I find the required reference?

thank you